# Limit Distribution of $\sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{\bar{X}_n}{S_n}$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Consider a sequence of random variables $\{X_1, ..., X_n \}$ where $X_k \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$  $\forall k=1,..., n$ and $\operatorname{Corr}(X_k, X_{k+h}) = \phi^h$, where $0<\phi<1$ and $h=1,...,n-1$. Suppose that

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{Var} \left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2 \right] = 0, \tag{1}
\end{align}

Determine the limit distribution of the quotient
$$
\sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{\bar{X}_n}{ S_n}
$$
where
$$
\bar{X}_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i/n \qquad \text{and} \qquad S^2_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X}_n)^2/(n-1).
$$

**Attempt.** First, notice that

\begin{align}
\sqrt{n} \frac{\bar{X}_n}{S_n} &= \frac{\sigma}{S_n} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n} \bar{X}_n}{\sigma} \\
&= \frac{\sigma}{S_n} \cdot \frac{\bar{X}_n}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}.
\end{align}

Now recall that $S_n \stackrel{P}{\to} \sigma$, that is, $S_n$ converges in probabiltiy to $\sigma$, so $\sigma/S_n \stackrel{P}{\to} 1$.

What's left is determine the limit distribution of $\displaystyle \frac{\bar{X}_n}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$, and invoke Slutsky's Theorem. Notice that this expression looks identical to the Central Limit Theorem, **however**... the $X_i's$ aren't i.i.d, that is, they are identically distributed by hypothesis, but they're not independent.

I'm stuck here and any help is appreciated. I guess that's where hypothesis $(1)$ comes in, because I haven't used it thus far.

Comment: Condition (1) looks like it's there to make $\mathrm{var}(S_n^2)\to 0$, to give convergence of $S_n$ to $\sigma$ in the presence of the correlation.  I'd be a bit surprised if it were enough to give a CLT assuming $X_i$ were marginally Normal but not jointly Normal.  How hard is this question supposed to be?

Comment: Undergrad math stats class, the textbook is Casella's book. The professor likes to give students a more challenging problem from time to time.